# Android: Send notifications to all users

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase

I have been googling for a lot of time but I couldn't find any solution to my problem: I want to use FireBased messaging in android, in order to send notifications to ALL the users who downloaded my app.

I tried to find good tutorials but I found just some that shows how ro send for one person at a time, and not something generic to all of the users, and I also couldn't find a good tutorial that explains how to install the FCM and that actually works...

are there anyone that can direct me or guide me to something that I can use?

any help or directions on how to do it with FCM or is there any other good and simpler solution?

thank you

EDIT:

I have been trying to install the firebase messaging, so I edited my manifest and added those services:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
 </intent-filter>
</service>
```

also updated my gradle files and added what I needed.

but when trying to run the app I keep getting this error log message:
`FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE`

any help please?

part of my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!--
        Defining Services
    -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

my firebased files:

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

//Class extending FirebaseInstanceIdService
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
    }
}
```

the second file:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import activity.MainActivity;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: use topics instead of device token

Comment: I have problems even before that... when trying to use firebase it shows this error: `FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE`

Comment: do you have the service registered in your manifest ?

Comment: yes I have it registered

Comment: update the code with proper details - manifest - service file

Comment: @Shubhank I updated my question, thank you

Comment: post your full manifest file and service class in the question

Comment: are you using the latest firebase version in gradle ?